# Get-MgUser Provisioningerrors always null

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, active-directory

Does anyone know if there is a way to get AAD Connect provisioning errors via Graph?  MSOL cmdlets still work, but Get-MGUser doesn't return the error.

This works:

```
(Get-MsolUser -ObjectId $objectId).dirsyncprovisioningerrors
```

This always returns null:

```
Get-MgUser -UserId $objectId | Select-Object provisioningerrors
```

Comment: Did you mean `| Select-Object onPremisesProvisioningErrors` ?

Comment: No, but that is exactly what I needed. Thanks Santiago. `Get-MgUser -UserId $objectId | Select-Object -ExpandProperty OnPremisesProvisioningErrors`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Graph, the property you're looking for is [`onPremisesProvisioningErrors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onpremisesprovisioningerror?view=graph-rest-beta), you need to also ensure you are using the [`beta` users API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta). If you want to find all objects with sync errors you can use the following filter:

```bash
Select-MgProfile beta
Get-MgUser -Filter "onPremisesProvisioningErrors/any(o:o/category eq 'PropertyConflict')" -All |
    ForEach-Object onPremisesProvisioningErrors
```